# I got difference in php-date and sql-now . I want both same

Tags: php, mysql

I got difference in `php-date` and `sql-now`.
I need help to make both time equal.

```
[php_date] = 2015-01-19 05:36:52

[sql_now] = 2015-01-19 05:38:13
```

Solutions & hint really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, first and the most important question: were these function called at the same time? I think both are already in UTC, if you mean the timezone (there are no timezones with only 1 minute difference)

Comment: Generally speaking, though you might tune up and synch the times using time servers etc, you **can not expect and rely on equality of time values came from different sources**. This will bring errors in your code.

Comment: @AndrewT. Both are in UTC, still both are giving diffrenet values! I want both same value. They differs 40 to 43 secs. I need 0 difference.

Comment: are php and mysql running on the same server?

Comment: @billynoah, yes both are running on same.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and MySQL are separate processes with their own default timezone configurations. You’re unlikely to run into timezone issues during development or if you’re deploying a single web application to your server. In that situation, PHP and MySQL can use the server’s time settings.
Prefer Following link definitely it will helpful.

http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/

Answer (score -3):

In your mysql and PHP server are operating on different timezone or their clocks are not properly synchronized, if its not then you wont have any issue.

Comment: server configuration. mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; will let you check the mysql timezone, date_default_timezone_get()

Comment: I checked. Both are in UTC.